# Loop dentro da Tabela PHP

Tags: php

Bom dia!!!
Estou tentando criar um relatório de notas de alunos utilizando PHP, o fato é que criei uma tabela para que listasse as notas vertical dentro de um loop, porém pra cada aluno é gerado uma tabela, não estou conseguindo tabular o resultado lado a lado . Preciso também que a cada vez que mude o instrutor repita o cabeçalho, ou seja a cada 8 linhas...

Segue o código:

```
<?php include_once "con_odbc.php" ?>
<div class="hidden-print"><b style=color:#ff0000><h4>Selecione o curso</h4></b>   <form method="get" >
 <select name="data" id="data">

<?php           

$tal=0;
$total =0;
$res=0;
$x=0;

$sqlquery=("SELECT apde.CadCrs.idCadCrs,
  apde.CadCrs.Abrev as Data,
  apde.CadCrs.Per,
  apde.CadCrs.DtIni,
  apde.CadCrs.DtFin,
  apde.CadCrs.Flag
FROM apde.CadCrs");
$res = odbc_exec($connect, $sqlquery); 

while ($dados =odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
echo("<option value='".$dados['Data']."'>".$dados['Data']."</option>");
}
?>
</select>
       </tr>
        <tr>
       </tr>
</table>
<td> <input type="submit" name="OK" value="Mostrar"><td><a class="btn btn-default ewExportLink ewPrint" onclick="window.print();" title=""  >
<span  class="icon-print ewIcon"></a></div><br>
<bgcolor='#FFFFCC'><div class="hidden-print"><a href="#abaixo" name="topo"><input type='button'   value="IR PARA O FIM"></a></div>

<div class="modal-content" width="600px">
 <div class="modal-content" >
  <div class="modal-header">
<span id=layer1 class=a1></span>
<span id=layer1 class=a1></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<br>

</form>

<br>

<table width="950" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<thead>
<TR bgcolor="<?php echo ($ac_sw1++%2==0)?"#E4E4E4":"#FFFFFF"; ?>" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=''">
    <TD COLSPAN="40"><CENTER><b><font color="red" face="Times New Roman">Relatório de Notas </font> </b></CENTER></TD>
    </TR>
    <tr bgcolor="<?php echo ($ac_sw1++%2==0)?"#E4E4E4":"#FFFFFF"; ?>" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=''">
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Curso</td>
    <td>Instrutor</td>
    <td>Critério</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>36</td>

    </tr></thead><tbody>

<?php

if(isset($_GET["OK"])){
     $Data= $_GET["data"];

$contador = 0;

 $sqlquery=("SELECT Abrev, NomGue, TipAval, Aluno_1, Aluno_2, Aluno_3, Aluno_4, Aluno_5, Aluno_6, Aluno_7, Aluno_8, Aluno_9, Aluno_10, Aluno_11, Aluno_12, Aluno_13, Aluno_14, Aluno_15, Aluno_16, Aluno_17, Aluno_18, Aluno_19, Aluno_20, Aluno_21, Aluno_22, Aluno_23, Aluno_24, Aluno_25, Aluno_26, Aluno_27, Aluno_28, Aluno_29, Aluno_30, Aluno_31, Aluno_32, Aluno_33, Aluno_34, Aluno_35, Aluno_36 FROM APDE.apde.V_AvInstru  where Abrev = '$Data'  order by NomGue asc");
$res = odbc_exec($connect, $sqlquery);

while ($dados =odbc_fetch_array($res) )
{

    if($contador == 8)
    {
?></tr>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

    <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr bgcolor="<?php echo ($ac_sw1++%2==0)?"#E4E4E4":"#FFFFFF"; ?>" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=''">
            <td width="35" height="22" align="center">ID</td>

            <td width="500" align="center">Curso</td>

            <td width="500" align="center">
               Instrutor</td>


            <td width="400">Critério
            </td>
    <td  width="50">1</td>
    <td  width="50">2</td>
    <td width="50">3</td>
    <td width="50">4</td>
    <td width="50">5</td>
    <td width="50">6</td>
    <td width="50">7</td>
    <td width="50">8</td>
    <td width="50">9</td>
    <td width="50">10</td>
    <td width="50">11</td>
    <td width="50">12</td>
    <td width="50">13</td>
    <td width="50">14</td>
    <td width="50">15</td>
    <td width="50">16</td>
    <td width="50">17</td>
    <td width="50">18</td>
    <td width="50">19</td>
    <td width="50">20</td>
    <td width="50">21</td>
    <td width="50">22</td>
    <td width="50">23</td>
    <td width="50">24</td>
    <td width="50">25</td>
    <td width="50">26</td>
    <td width="50">27</td>
    <td width="50">28</td>
    <td width="50">29</td>
    <td width="50">30</td>
    <td width="50">31</td>
    <td width="50">32</td>
    <td width="50">33</td>
    <td width="50">34</td>
    <td width="50">35</td>
    <td width="50">36</td>


    </tr></thead><tr>

<?php    
        $contador = 0;
    }

?>

        <tr bgcolor="<?php echo ($ac_sw1++%2==0)?"#E4E4E4":"#FFFFFF"; ?>" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=''">
            <td width="35" height="22" align="center"><?php echo $contador; ?></td>

            <td width="500" align="center"><?php echo $dados['Abrev']; ?></td>

            <td width="133" align="center">
               <?php echo $dados['NomGue']; ?></td>

            <td width="400"><?php echo $dados['TipAval']; ?>
            </td>

            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_1']; ?></td>        
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_2']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_3']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_4']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_5']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_6']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_7']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_8']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_9']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_10']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_11']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_12']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_13']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_14']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_15']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_16']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_17']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_18']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_19']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_20']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_21']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_22']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_23']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_24']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_25']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_26']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_27']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_28']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_29']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_30']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_31']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_32']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_33']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_34']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_35']; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $dados['Aluno_36']; ?></td>

        </tr>

<?php
    $contador++;
}} 
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá... não tenho como verificar se ficou certo... fiz o possível. Sei que é bastante fácil a gente se perder quando esta trabalhando em um arquivo assim, com PHP e HTML misturado.. Segue o que consegui fazer.. por favor, verifique se ficou correto. E tente cuidar mais a estrutura do seu código. Tinha tags cruzadas, e tr's perdidos e abertura de tables a mais..

```
<?php include_once "con_odbc.php" ?>
<div class="hidden-print"><b style=color:#ff0000>
   <h4>Selecione o curso</h4>
</b>

<form method="get">
    <select name="data" id="data">
        <?php           

            $tal=0;
            $total =0;
            $res=0;
            $x=0;

            $sqlquery=("SELECT apde.CadCrs.idCadCrs,
            apde.CadCrs.Abrev as Data,
            apde.CadCrs.Per,
            apde.CadCrs.DtIni,
            apde.CadCrs.DtFin,
            apde.CadCrs.Flag
            FROM apde.CadCrs");
            $res = odbc_exec($connect, $sqlquery); 
        ?>
        <?php  while ($dados =odbc_fetch_array($res)): ?>
        <option value='".$dados[' Data ']."'>
            <?= $dados['Data'] ?>
        </option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="OK" value="Mostrar">
    <a class="btn btn-default ewExportLink ewPrint" onclick="window.print();" title="">
        <span class="icon-print ewIcon">
    </a>
</form>
```

```
 <bgcolor='#FFFFCC'><div class="hidden-print"><a href="#abaixo" name="topo"><input type='button' value="IR PARA O FIM"></a></div>

<div class="modal-content" width="600px">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span id=layer1 class=a1></span>
            <span id=layer1 class=a1></span>
            <br>
            <br>

            <table width="950" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <thead>
                    <TR bgcolor="<?php echo ($ac_sw1++%2==0)?" #E4E4E4 ":"#FFFFFF "; ?>" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=''">
                        <TD COLSPAN="40">
                            <CENTER>
                                <b>
                                    <font color="red" face="Times New Roman">Relatório de Notas </font>
                                </b>
                            </CENTER>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                    <tr bgcolor="<?php echo ($ac_sw1++%2==0)?" #E4E4E4 ":"#FFFFFF "; ?>" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=''">
                        <td>Id</td>
                        <td>Curso</td>
                        <td>Instrutor</td>
                        <td>Critério</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                        <td>18</td>
                        <td>19</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>21</td>
                        <td>22</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td>24</td>
                        <td>25</td>
                        <td>26</td>
                        <td>27</td>
                        <td>28</td>
                        <td>29</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>31</td>
                        <td>32</td>
                        <td>33</td>
                        <td>34</td>
                        <td>35</td>
                        <td>36</td>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <?php if(isset($_GET["OK"])): ?>

                    <?php
                            $Data= $_GET["data"];

                            $contador = 0;

                            $sqlquery=("SELECT Abrev, NomGue, TipAval, Aluno_1, Aluno_2, Aluno_3, Aluno_4, Aluno_5, Aluno_6, Aluno_7, Aluno_8, Aluno_9, Aluno_10, Aluno_11, Aluno_12, Aluno_13, Aluno_14, Aluno_15, Aluno_16, Aluno_17, Aluno_18, Aluno_19, Aluno_20, Aluno_21, Aluno_22, Aluno_23, Aluno_24, Aluno_25, Aluno_26, Aluno_27, Aluno_28, Aluno_29, Aluno_30, Aluno_31, Aluno_32, Aluno_33, Aluno_34, Aluno_35, Aluno_36 FROM APDE.apde.V_AvInstru  where Abrev = '$Data'  order by NomGue asc");
                            $res = odbc_exec($connect, $sqlquery);
                    ?>
                        <?php while ($dados =odbc_fetch_array($res) ): ?>
                        <?php if($contador == 8): ?>

                        <tr bgcolor="<?php echo ($ac_sw1++%2==0)?" #E4E4E4 ":"#FFFFFF "; ?>" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=''">
                            <td width="35" height="22" align="center">ID</td>
                            <td width="500" align="center">Curso</td>
                            <td width="500" align="center">Instrutor</td>
                            <td width="400">Critério</td>
                            <td width="50">1</td>
                            <td width="50">2</td>
                            <td width="50">3</td>
                            <td width="50">4</td>
                            <td width="50">5</td>
                            <td width="50">6</td>
                            <td width="50">7</td>
                            <td width="50">8</td>
                            <td width="50">9</td>
                            <td width="50">10</td>
                            <td width="50">11</td>
                            <td width="50">12</td>
                            <td width="50">13</td>
                            <td width="50">14</td>
                            <td width="50">15</td>
                            <td width="50">16</td>
                            <td width="50">17</td>
                            <td width="50">18</td>
                            <td width="50">19</td>
                            <td width="50">20</td>
                            <td width="50">21</td>
                            <td width="50">22</td>
                            <td width="50">23</td>
                            <td width="50">24</td>
                            <td width="50">25</td>
                            <td width="50">26</td>
                            <td width="50">27</td>
                            <td width="50">28</td>
                            <td width="50">29</td>
                            <td width="50">30</td>
                            <td width="50">31</td>
                            <td width="50">32</td>
                            <td width="50">33</td>
                            <td width="50">34</td>
                            <td width="50">35</td>
                            <td width="50">36</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php $contador = 0; endif; ?>

                        <tr bgcolor="<?php echo ($ac_sw1++%2==0)?" #E4E4E4 ":"#FFFFFF "; ?>" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=''">

                            <td width="35" height="22" align="center"><?= $contador; ?></td>
                            <td width="500" align="center"><?= $dados['Abrev']; ?></td>
                            <td width="133" align="center"><?= $dados['NomGue']; ?></td>
                            <td width="400"><?= $dados['TipAval']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_1']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_2']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_3']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_4']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_5']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_6']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_7']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_8']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_9']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_10']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_11']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_12']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_13']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_14']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_15']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_16']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_17']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_18']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_19']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_20']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_21']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_22']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_23']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_24']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_25']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_26']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_27']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_28']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_29']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_30']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_31']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_32']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_33']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_34']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_35']; ?></td>
                            <td width="50"><?= $dados['Aluno_36']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php $contador++; endwhile; endif; ?>
            </table>
```

Comment: Olá, obrigada pelo empenho e pelas dicas, fiz o teste por aqui e o erro permanece continua repetindo as tabelas para cada aluno...